# Installing libcurl for Visual Studio 2019 for x64 package

Tags: curl, visual-studio-2019, libcurl

I've attempted the following to get the lib curl installed for Visual Studio 2019 but it is not working. The libcurl.lib file is 20 KB which is incorrect.

```
vcpkg install curl:x64-windows
```

I also do not find the VS2019 directory under curl-7.87.0\projects\Windows directory.

What is the correct approach to build X64 version of libcurl for VS2019?

Comment: *The libcurl.lib file is 20 KB which is incorrect.* It's correct. It's an import library for the dll.

Comment: Thanks @273K. Able to build the solution using nmake.